# Writing apache 2 access log to 2 locations

Tags: apache-2.2

we want to temporarily write access logs for vhosts to 2 locations. (One for its own log and one for a shared log for all sites).

We want to do this in order to watch http requests from all sites in 1 location. Is this possible?

Comment: Did my answer to your question work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html):

> Multiple access logs can be created simply by specifying multiple CustomLog directives in the configuration file.

Just set multiple hosts to use the same CustomLog.